# Sorting using quicksort doesn't give sorted array

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I started learning algorithm in `C++` and stuck with `Quicksort`. But I'm unable to get the bug in my code that is not sorting the array properly.

Here is the link to [code](http://ideone.com/3xWOOY) or here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int array[], int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cout << array[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void swap(int* a, int *b) {
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

int partition(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
  int pivot = arr[hi];
  int i = lo - 1;
  for (int j = lo; j < hi-1; j++) {
    if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
        i +=1;
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
  }

  swap(&arr[i+1], &arr[hi]);
  return i+1;
  }

  void quicksort(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo < hi) {
      int p = partition(arr, lo, hi);
      quicksort(arr, lo, p-1 );
      printArray(arr, 8);
      quicksort(arr, p + 1, hi);
    }
  }

 int main() {
   int len;
   int array[] = {2,8,7,1,3,5,6,4};
   len = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
   quicksort(array, 0, len-1);
   printArray(array, len);
   return 0;
 }
```

I'm printing the array elements so that I can see the behavior of array elements.

Comment: You have a debugger, learn how to use it. That's usually working better than head scratching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation looks very close to the pseudocode on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (with `j` in `partition(..)` in your code being called `i` in the Wikipedia article and `i` in your code having the name `storeIndex`)

But there are two differences, one of which at least causes the algorithm to fail on your example:

```
for (int j = lo; j < hi-1; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = lo; j <= hi-1; j++)
```

the Wikipedia article says `for i from lo to hi−1, inclusive` hence the `<=` instead of `<`.

Another difference is that in your code you have

```
if (arr[j] <= pivot)
```

while the Wikipedia article has

```
if A[i] < pivotValue
```

so `<` instead of `<=` .

Comment: thanks for the help!! I didn't look to the iterator in foor loop! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Please change your `for` loop from:

```
for (int j = lo; j < hi-1; j++)
```

to

```
for (int j = lo; j < hi; j++)
```

or

```
for (int j = lo; j <= hi-1; j++)
```

The reason being the array must be handled right from `lo` to `hi`(**inclusive**).

But, in your attempt it was taking only

> *{lo, low+1, ..., hi-1}*

into account instead of

> *{lo, low+1, ..., hi-1, **hi**}*

Comment: Thanks for the help!!